# message from client to server in C

Tags: c

I have such a task, I need to write the “client” code so that the message from the “client” is sent to the server (which was created by my teacher, ip “127.0.0.1”). After the message arrives at the server (for example, “Nursultan Nazarbayev”, the server will reply “ok” and the client should send “quit”)

I'm just learning C. How to make a break with the server? I wanted to send "quit", but this did not work, there was a constant error, how can I do this?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
char message[2048];//=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));// transmission message
char buf[sizeof(message)];
int port,ch;
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if(argc!=3){
printf("Wrong number of arguments!\nThere must be 2 arguments (Port, server ip-address)!\n");
exit(0);
}

    int sock;                 // socket descriptor

    struct sockaddr_in addr; // structure with address
    struct hostent* hostinfo;
port = atoi(argv[1]);
hostinfo = argv[2];
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // create TCP socket
    if(sock < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Specify server parameters
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET; // Internet domains
    addr.sin_port = htons(port); // or any other port ...
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("hostinfo");

   // addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
      //addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host_ip);

 if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) // establishing a connection to the server
    {
        perror("Connection");
        exit(2);
    }

while(1){//WHILE <---
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    printf("Enter a message to the server (To exit: quit): "); 
    if (!strcmp(gets(message), "quit")){close(sock);return 0;}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    printf("sending a message to the server...\n");
    send(sock, message, sizeof(message), 0); // sending a message to the server
    int bytes_read = 0;
    printf("Message Waiting\n");
    bytes_read = recv(sock, buf, sizeof(message), 0);
    printf("received %d bytes\tMessage: %s\n", bytes_read, buf); // receiving a message from the server

}//END_WHILE

return 0;

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You need to clarify what precisely is the problem you are facing and what have you tried to solve it.

Comment: Also, better formatting of the code example would be nice. Badly formatted code discourages people from reading it.

Comment: Avoid using `gets`

Comment: Are messages always exactly 2048 bytes? If not, how are messages delimited? And where's the code to receive a message?

Answer (score 0):

This probably is wrong:

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("hostinfo");
```

You are passing the literal string, `"hostinfo"` to the `inet_addr()` function. Meanwhile, you have a *variable* named `hostinfo`, to which you assign a string value, but you never use it anywhere in the program.

Maybe you meant to do this instead:

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(hostinfo);
```

---

P.S., I like long, descriptive names. If that was my program, the name of the variable would be something like, `server_address_as_string`.